# libreoffice sub heading numbering for right to left language

Tags: libreoffice-writer

I write Arabic in LibreOffice.
 How can I write a heading and LibreOffice generates automatically the numbers for example:

```
       first chapter (1
      second chapter (2
  section one (1-2
  section two (2-2
section three (3-2
```

Note that when I write in English it is easy and I can do that, but for "Right to Left Languages" it doesn't work correctly and I can only produce below numbering which is false:

```
    first chapter (1
   second chapter (2

  section one (2-1

  section two (2-2

section three (2-3
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Possible workaround: Customize the numbering (Format|Bullets and Numbering|Options): In the before or 'after' separator field, and add an [LRM](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200e/) character to force the direction.

Answer (score 0):

wrong text in liber office:
`یاد بگیریم ++c سلام بیا`

correct text must be:
`یاد بگیریم c++ سلام بیا`

To correct first sentence, you must append [Left-to-right mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Left-to-right_mark)
end of c++ (in other words, after second +).

**How we can add this character?**

go to `insert > special character...` in Libreoffice Writer, then a window will be open that contains many characters. chose one of fonts that has `U+200E` character (see  [list of fonts that support U+200E](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200e/fontsupport.htm)) and then click OK.
finally you must see somthings like bellow:

`یاد بگیریم c++ سلام بیا`